# Was ist die Abkürzung von "Stellvertretung"?

Tags: abbreviation

Was ist die korrekte Abkürzung vom Wort *Stellvertretung*?

Im online Duden habe ich keinen Hinweis auf eine offizielle Abkürzung gefunden: http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Stellvertretung

Im Internet (auf Wiktionary und Woxikon) und bei Kollegen habe ich folgende Varianten gesehen, wobei ich nicht weiss, ob das eigene Erfindungen sind oder nicht:

- [StV](http://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/stellv..php) (ohne Punkt, grosses V)
- [Stv.](http://abkuerzungen.woxikon.de/abkuerzung/stellv..php) (mit Punkt)
- [Stellv.](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stellv.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Für viele Abkürzungen gibt es keine amtlichen (also offiziell festgelegten) Regeln, die ihre Richtigkeit belegen. Somit hat man eine Art Freibrief in der Wahl der Abkürzung. Man sollte immer bedenken, dass die Abkürzung beim Adressaten verstanden wird.

> Desh. auf Abk. o. Ä. i. Allg. verz.! <sup>*</sup>

Für den "Stellvertreter" gilt, wie im Übrigen für alle Abkürzungen, dass ein [Nomen **niemals** klein geschrieben wird](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/abkuerzungen), also auch nicht in einer Abkürzung. So werden auch die mehr oder minder gebräuchlichen Abkürzungen für *Stellvertreter/Stellvertretung* wie folgt geschrieben:

> Stellv. - Stv. - StV<sub>([ohne Punkt](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibregeln/abkuerzungen))</sub>

Ausnahmen mit etablierten Regeln sind die beiden allgemein gebräuchliche Abkürzung für einen Vertreter (der in dieser Bedeutung immer auch ein Stellvertreter ist):

- **i. V.:** kennzeichnet eine Unterschrift als *"in Vertretung"*
- **o. V. i. A.:** offizielle Post darf auch von einem Vertreter im Amt (*"oder Vertreter im Amt"*) geöffnet und bearbeitet werden.

<sup>*</sup><sub>Deshalb auf Abkürzungen oder Ähnliches im Allgemeinen verzichten!</sub>

Comment: "i.A." heißt aber "im Auftrag"; deshalb kürzt man seit der Rechtschreibreform "im Allgemeinen" mit "i.Allg." ab.

Comment: @celtschk: Umso mehr ein Grund, auf Abkürzungen zu verzichten ;)

Comment: Wo kommt das große V her? Wieso dann nicht auch sTv?

Comment: @userunknown: da musst Du die Leute fragen, die diese Abkürzung erfunden haben. Ich nehme mal stark an, es kommt daher, dass ein *"Vertreter"* ein Nomen ist.

Comment: Der Begriff ist aber nicht "Stell Vertreter" sondern "Stellvertreter". "Treter" ist ja auch ein Nomen. Also die Logik erschließt sich mir nicht.

Comment: Die Abkürzung i.V. bedeutet immer nur in Vollmacht.
Wer diese Vollmacht nicht hat und in Vertretung mal schnell die Abkürzung i.V. benutzt, kann sich damit jede Menge Ärger einhandeln.

Comment: @Rapante: Diese Aussage sollte mit einer Quelle belegt werden.

Answer (score 4):

*StV* ist schon mal insofern Humbug, da in Stellvertretung gar kein großes V drin vorkommt.

Der [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/stellvertretend) listet unter dem Adjektiv *stellvertretend* die Abkürzung *stv.* (natürlich mit Punkt, genauso wie wir *i.d.R.* auch sonst immer ein Punkt verwenden, wie *z.B.* in *Abk.*). Wikipedia - wie OP bereits verlinkt hat - definiert die Abkürzung *stellv.* für *[Stellvertreter](http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Stellvertreter)*. Letztere ist meiner Meinung nach auch die sinnvollere (ich zumindest vermisse ein O, wenn ich *stv* höre und denke eher an die Straßenverkehrsordnung :D ) und geläufigere Variante, man findet auch massig Onlinebeispiele dazu. Zum Beispiel im [Impressum der Zeit](http://www.zeit.de/impressum/index).

Des Weiteren hat eine kurze Onlinesuche in verschiedenen Impressen gezeigt, dass *stv.* bestenfalls als Abkürzung für etwas in der Art *Sport- und Turnverein* verwendet wird, während die kontextbezogene Trefferquote mit *stellv.* wesentlich höher war.

Ich denke, für gewöhnlich wird aber damit immer das Adjektiv oder die Bezeichung *StellvertreterIn* abgekürzt, nicht aber *Stellvertretung*, was aber daran liegen kann, das Letzteres generell am seltesten verwendet wird.

---

Wenn wir schon beim Thema sind, möchte ich noch anmerken, dass auch die Abkürzung *i.V.* existiert, welche entw. *in Vollmacht* (Handlungsvollmacht) oder *in Vertretung* (Stellvertretung) bedeutet; aber bitte nicht verwechseln mit *i.A.*, was *in Auftrag* bedeutet (was eine andere rechtliche Bedeutung mit sich zieht).